# Android Studio、Unityで3DモデルをAndroid端末向けにデスクトップマスコットとして表示できるか？

Tags: android, unity3d

お世話になっております。
タイトル通りとなりますが、Android StudioもしくはUnityを用いて、Blenderで作成した3DモデルをAndroid端末向けにデスクトップマスコットとして表示できますか？
イメージとして、docomoのしゃべってコンシェルのような表示になります。

もし、表示可能なら方法も教えていただくと幸いです。

Answer (score 2):

3Dモデルであることと、Home画面でOverlay表示させること(デスクトップマスコット)は無関係ですので
単にHome画面でOverlay表示させることについて説明いたします。
(そこに指定するのは3Dモデルであってもなくても構いません)

結論から言うと「力技で出来る」となります。
要素的には以下の3つになります
1. 作成されたアプリを常にOverlay表示する
2. 別アプリは遷移できるように1.はActivityではなくService化する
3. Home画面のみそれを実行する(3.が力技が必要)

1.については
WindowManager.LayoutParamsを使用して、typeに作成されたいWindowをOverlay表示させる種別に設定すれば良いです。
例えばTYPE_PHONEです。
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html

これだけですとただのActivityですのでbackキーを押した場合等に消えてしまいますので、
Serviceとして実装する必要があります。

```
public class MyService extends Service {
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            ～目的に従って任意にparameter指定～
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay, null);

    ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).addView(view, params);
```

3.が一番厄介なのですが、
ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo等でHomeが動作している間を監視する等しかない気がします。(この方法だと権限も必要だし、対象Homeアプリをハードコーディングする必要があるので非常に限定的です。)
しゃべってコンシェルもHomeアプリによって挙動が変わるようなので力技でやっているのではないのでしょうか。。。

(追記)ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfoはAPILevel21より制約が厳しくなりSystemOrSignatureしか使用できなくなっておりました。。。

---

また、アプローチは変わりますがしゃべってコンシェルのように「HomeアプリのOverlay」
ではなく「Homeアプリの背景」ならば
LiveWallPaperとして実装する方法があります。
こちらの方がシンプルですが、インタラクティブであるもののあくまで壁紙扱いになってしまいます。
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/wallpaper/WallpaperService.html

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。  3に関しては本当に骨が折れそうですね。。。  1、2に関しては以前実行することができた(3‌​Dモデルは使っていない)ので、何とかなり‌​そうです。  質問内容以前の話になってし‌​まうかもしれませんが、3DモデルとSer‌​viceについて伺いたいことがあります。‌​  Android Studioで3Dモデルを使用したい場合はOpenGLが一番手軽のものになりますか？  また、UnityでService‌​を使用するとしたら、プラグインを新たに作‌​る必要がありますか？またはできないですか‌​？  検討外れ、初歩的な質問をしてすみま‌​せん。  追加で回答していただいているL‌​iveWallPaperは今回の意図とは‌​異なりますが、教えていただきありがとうご‌​ざいます。わざわざすみません。

Comment: すみません、Unityに詳しくないもので別レコードを起票いただいた方が良いと思います・・・基本はOpenGLを使用しています。